# Calculate percentage value for each column based on above two row value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL query

```
SELECT Status, APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,JAN,FEB,MAR
FROM CallStatus;
```

I get the below output like this:

[image]

Now I want to calculate the percentage value for each column based on above two row value. So the output would look like this:

[image]

I have tried to transpose the table and calculate the percentage value and re-transpose back but no success. Below is what I have tried so far:

```
select [Ongoing], [Complete]
from
(
  select CStatus, name, value
  from CallStatus
  unpivot
  (
    value for name in (APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,JAN,FEB,MAR)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
 sum(value)
  for CStatus in ([Ongoing], [Complete])
) piv
```

Comment: Why did the value of complete all change in your second image? *Consumable* sample data, and expected results, however, will help us help you. Please don't post images of data, it doesn't help us help you.

Comment: @dale-k:  `tsql`?  Why did you add that ?

Comment: Because that's the dialect SQL Server uses, @Luuk ... You can see this is the tag's exerpt [[tag:tsql]]: *"T-SQL (Transact Structured Query Language) is the extension of SQL functionality supported by Sybase ASE and Microsoft SQL Server."*

Comment: But the question has nothing to do with anything that is tsql specific. Pivoting is Microsoft (ms-sql-server) specific.

Comment: You should use `group by` with `ROLLUP`...

Comment: @Luuk `PIVOT` is a T-SQL operator... Though, personally, I would recommend the OP uses conditional aggregation. Either way, that doesn't change the fact the the OP requires a solution in T-SQL (as a opposed to [[tag:plsql]] or [[tag:ansi-sql]]) as *that* is the dialect SQL Server uses.

Comment: @Larnu: so, the `sql` tag becomes unneeded because that is implied when the `tsql` tag is mentioned.

Comment: @Luuk if one is writing a SQL query targeting SQL Server, then one is asking for a solution in T-SQL. Its not saying the solution requires specific features of T-SQL - OP rarely knows this in advance.

Comment: It's still SQL, @Luuk ... T-SQL is a dialect of SQL... We are, however, derailing the comments here.

Comment: As I alluded to in my other [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904101/calculate-percentage-value-for-each-column-based-on-above-two-row-value-in-sql#comment121774482_68904101) I suspect getting the answer you want would be much easier with a different approach; most likely conditional aggregation. For us, however, to be able to do this we really need that consumable sample data. Please don't expect us to transcribe your data *for you*; we won't. You are in a far better position to do so. This is especially true when your sample data and expected results are completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a given table structure and sample data this is a bit trial on error, but given the information you provided I guess you can solve this in a "simple" query without pivoting etc. ... anyways, my approach does not feature the rightmost columns with the totals - but you should be able to add those yourself.
However, judging by your sample query you have one column for status and one value column per month, so the query can be simple as the following:

```
DECLARE @CallStatus TABLE(
[status] nvarchar(20)
,JAN int, FEB int, MAR int, APR int, MAY int, JUN int, JUL int, AUG int, SEP int, OCT int, NOV int, [DEC] int
)

INSERT INTO @CallStatus VALUES
('Ongoing', null, null, null, 10,12,50,30,15,null, null, null, null)
,('Complete', null, null, null, 40,20,5,12,10,null, null, null, null);

WITh cte AS(
SELECT Status, ISNULL(APR,0) APR, ISNULL(MAY, 0) MAY,ISNULL(JUN, 0) JUN, ISNULL(JUL, 0) JUL, ISNULL(AUG, 0) AUG,ISNULL(SEP, 0) SEP
             , ISNULL(OCT, 0) OCT,ISNULL(NOV, 0) NOV,ISNULL([DEC], 0) [DEC],ISNULL(JAN, 0) JAN,ISNULL(FEB, 0) FEB,ISNULL(MAR, 0) MAR
FROM @CallStatus
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Totals' AS Status, SUM(ISNULL(APR,0)), SUM(ISNULL(MAY,0)), SUM(ISNULL(JUN,0)), SUM(ISNULL(JUL,0)), SUM(ISNULL(AUG,0)), SUM(ISNULL(SEP,0))
                         , SUM(ISNULL(OCT,0)), SUM(ISNULL(NOV,0)), SUM(ISNULL([DEC],0)), SUM(ISNULL(JAN,0)), SUM(ISNULL(FEB,0)), SUM(ISNULL(MAR,0))
FROM @CallStatus
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE status IN ('Complete', 'Ongoing')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Percentage' AS Status, CASE WHEN t.APR = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.APR*1.0/t.APR)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.may = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.may*1.0/t.may)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.jun = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.jun*1.0/t.jun)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.jul = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.jul*1.0/t.jul)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.aug = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.aug*1.0/t.aug)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.sep = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.sep*1.0/t.sep)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.oct = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.oct*1.0/t.oct)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.nov = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.nov*1.0/t.nov)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.dec = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.dec*1.0/t.dec)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.jan = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.jan*1.0/t.jan)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.feb = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.feb*1.0/t.feb)*100 END
                             , CASE WHEN t.mar = 0 THEN 0.0 ELSE (c.mar*1.0/t.mar)*100 END
  FROM cte c
  JOIN cte t ON c.status = 'Complete' AND t.status = 'Totals'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are far better off with the table in the reverse: months as rows and aggregation in columns.

You can use `ROLLUP` or `GROUPING SETS` to get the `Total` row.

```sql
SELECT
  Month = CASE WHEN GROUPING(Month) = 0 THEN Month ELSE 'Total' END,
  Ongoing =   SUM(CASE WHEN CStatus = 'Ongoing' THEN value END),
  Completed = SUM(CASE WHEN CStatus = 'Complete' THEN value END),
  CompletedPercent = SUM(CASE WHEN CStatus = 'Complete' THEN value END) * 100.0 / SUM(value)
FROM (
  select CStatus, mnth, value
  from CallStatus
  unpivot
  (
    value for Month in (APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,JAN,FEB,MAR)
  ) unpiv
) src
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (Month),
  ()
);
```